# Build failure for example application cloud-s4-sdk-book (integration test)

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I have loaded a sample application for SCP / S/4HANA Business Partner integration, did changes as documented in read.me, I also have comm. user/arrangement in S/4HANA for 0008. 
When I try to build it,

I get error during integration test, the content of file `com.sap.cloud.s4hana.examples.addressmgr.BusinessPartnerServletTest is:`

```
    <<< ERROR!    org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.DeploymentException: Unable to deploy
    Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: /Users/d036682/Downloads/cloud_app/integration-tests/target/surefire-fork/1/arquillian-tomee-working-dir/0/292d95a8-4414-4535-846f-c8fae7dcd7e9: Cannot get Unsafe.defineClass
    Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: /Users/d036682/Downloads/cloud_app/integration-tests/target/surefire-fork/1/arquillian-tomee-working-dir/0/292d95a8-4414-4535-846f-c8fae7dcd7e9: Cannot get Unsafe.defineClass
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get Unsafe.defineClass
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(java.lang.String,[B,int,int,java.lang.ClassLoader,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
```

Could you please help

Thanks,
Konstantin

Comment: Hi Konstantin and welcome to SO. Please enhance your question with the version of the SDK you are using. Also please point us to the exact code you are using if possible, ideally in a minimal working example. The error message may indicate a mismatched dependency or jdk version, but we’ll need more information in order to tackle the issue.

Comment: Hi Florian, this is what I see from maven, I am not sure if this is what you are asking for: Apache Maven 3.6.1 (d66c9c0b3152b2e69ee9bac180bb8fcc8e6af555; 2019-04-04T21:00:29+02:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.1/libexec
Java version: 12.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-12.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home .  In blogs it is mentioned that only jdk 8 is supported, maybe this is why it does not work for me ? - although why only at integration test ?

Comment: Yes, please use JDK 8. For various reasons, later versions are not supported yet.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure to use [JDK 8 as documented](https://sap.github.io/cloud-s4-sdk-book/pages/setup.html) until further notice. Various dependencies don't work in later versions as of now.

Kind regards

Florian